# Google Script - How to find the index of a nested Array in the search Array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, indexof

I want to find the index of the NestedArray (userdata) inside the SearchArray (data). I already have the existing code inserted below.

```
var data = [["John",25],["James",19],["Liam",27],["George",22]]
var user = "Liam";
var userdata = [];

const userfound = data.some(function(row){
    if(row[0] == user){ 
      userdata = row; 
      return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
});

console.log(userfound);
console.log(data);
console.log(userdata);
```

The code above gives the corresponding log:

```
true
Array [Array ["John", 25], Array ["James", 19], Array ["Liam", 27], Array ["George", 22]]
Array ["Liam", 27]
```

normally I would try to find an index of an item in an Array like so:

```
const index = data.findIndex( x => userdata.includes(x));
```

However this doesn't work for a 2d Array. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function cantfindmyindex() {
  var data = [["John", 25], ["James", 19], ["Liam", 27], ["George", 22]];
  var user = "Liam";
  console.log(data.map(r => r[0]).indexOf(user));
}
```

Comment: Will this work on numeric values? Let's say I want to find indexOf 27?

Comment: Use it like this: `function cantfindmyindex() {
  var data = [["John", 25], ["James", 19], ["Liam", 27], ["George", 22]];
  var user = 27;
  console.log(data.map(r => r[1]).indexOf(user));
}`

Comment: I was actually doing that correctly. Where I was going wrong was I was putting the number in quotations. smh. Took the quotes off and it works. Thanks for the response and for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex()` with a 2 dimensional array as follows:

```js
var data = [["John",25],["James",19],["Liam",27],["George",22]]
var user = "Liam";

const isUser = (element) => element[0] === user;
console.log( data.findIndex(isUser) );
```

Here, `isUser` is a testing function that can be passed to `findIndex()`. Each `element` is an entry in the outer array - hence `element[0]` is the first value (the name) in each sub-array.

It will stop at the first successful match.